# Upload File Script won't load because it cannot find the function bt1Clicked()

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am attempting to let a client upload a file to my server in an ASP.NET C# website. I have created a simple script to introduce myself to the nuances of both uploading a file and also creating a script where all the code (HTML and C# code) is in the same file.

**My Problem:** The function `uploadFile()` never outputs/returns any string result when it should return a string describing if the upload succeeded or why it failed.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I have updated my web.config with the following code:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="folderPath" value="uploadedFiles"></add>
</appSettings>
```

PPS: Is there anything wrong with having my C# code & HTML all in the same .aspx file? Is it better to separate them out?

My Simple Code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/C#">
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.UI;
        using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
        using System.Configuration;

        protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputFile fileUpload;
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblMessage;
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btnSave;
        protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl test;

        protected void bt1Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (fileUpload.PostedFile != null)
            {
                string strFilename, strMessage;
                strFilename = fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
                strMessage = uploadFile(strFilename, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["folderPath"]);
                output.InnerHtml = strMessage;
            }
        }

        public string uploadFile(string fileName, string folderName)
        {
            if (fileName == "")
            {
               return "Invalid filename supplied";
            }
            if (fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength == 0)
            {
                return "Invalid file content";
            }
            fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            if (folderName == "")
            {
                return "Path not found";
            }
            try
            {
                if (fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength <= 2048000)
                {
                    fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(folderName) + "\\" + fileName);
                    return "File uploaded successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Unable to upload,file exceeds maximum limit";
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                return ex.Message + "Permission to upload file denied";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="fileUpload" type="file" Runat="server" NAME="fileUpload"/>
        <asp:button id="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Upload File" OnClick="bt1Clicked"></asp:button>
        <p id="output" runat="server">Result should be displayed here after clicking</p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to put your C# code in the front page, you'll need to put it in a `<script runat="server">` tag. When I do this (which is very rarely), I'll usually put the `<script>` tag after the HTML. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
</html>
<script runat="server">
//Code here
</script>
```

The advantage of using `<script runat="server">` is that if you are writing a Web Application (where the code compiles into a dll), you can create pages that run server side without doing a new build of the application (of course you'll have to remove the `CodeBehind` attribute from the `@Page` directive). So if you're in a situation where you can't do a new build for whatever reason, writing everything in the `.aspx` for a one off page can be useful.

That being said, you're probably better off writing the code in the codebehind file (In your case this is `test.aspx.cs`, and you can get to it in VS.NET by right clicking on `test.aspx` in the Solution Explorer and selecting "View Code" or by pressing F7 when you're viewing the `test.aspx` file). Using the codebehind file separates the code from the HTML, and more importantly compilation errors will be raised when you compile the application. If you use `<script runat="server">`, compilation errors won't be raised until the page is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your PPS - yes in general it is considered best practice to have your C# code in a separate file.  There are a few reasons for this, I'll list a few here for you:

1. Ease of maintenance - having the C# in another file makes it easier to fix or change things later
2. Easier for UI guys to work with - If you're working with a designy type person who's doing your HTML and CSS etc, it'll be easier for them to work with the mostly-html ASPX markup, without all the C# getting in the way
3. Precompiling - Your C# code can be precompiled away into a DLL if it's in a separate file, but if it's in an ASPX file it needs to be compiled by IIS when it is running.
4. There's probably a bunch of other reasons that I haven't mentioned too...

Some might say for a simple test/tutorial application you don't need to worry so much, but it's probably best to PRACTICE best practices while you are doing tutorials etc. so it doesn't seem foreign to you later on.

And if you have to put it all in one file for some reason, take rsbarro's advice above and put it in a completely separate block below the HTML so it's nice and clean.